# Bing Api not working for me

Tags: iphone, ios, bing

I am using Bing Api, My problem is very basic. I already generated App key, but I got error in output in console.

I am using this for JSON response

```
NSString *urlString=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@%@%@",
    @"http://api.search.live.net/json.aspx?Appid=xxxxxxxaxkOatx66TB+CX8qJUIZw=&query=",
    text,@"sources=web&web.offset=",offValue];


NSLog(@"%@",urlString);

NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
NSData *data=[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
```

output when i print respose is

```
SearchResponse =     {
    Errors =         (
                    {
            Code = 1002;
            HelpUrl = "http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd251042.aspx";
            Message = "Parameter has invalid value.";
            Parameter = "SearchRequest.AppId";
            Value = "zKHS8Fm WcwlhCFh8oYWcs VyUYddig=";
        }
    );
    Query =         {
        SearchTerms = iphone;
    };
    Version = "2.2";
};
```

}

What is the reason behind this error?

thanks All.

Comment: I think problem in my app key. (in my App key have special symbol + and =)

Answer (score 0):

The parameter you are reading sending in the server request contains wrongly spelled.Please give the proper names as similar to server implmentation.Just ask server code team to give request parameter names,and give the proper naming convention.It will fix the issue.The request should be key value pair,not like a string with all values separated by commas.Please give the correct request format.